# Python - Override environment variables homedrive and homepath

Tags: python, environment

Questions:
Is it not possible to override the `HOMEDRIVE` and `HOMEPATH` variables in Python? 
Where exactly are these variables stored, I do not see them in the Environment variables dialog box.

Explanation:

In Python you can access environment variables using

```
os.environ['variable_name']
```

For example, if I go to System Properties -> Advanced -> Environment variables, and I create a system variable named `GARY` with value `XYZ`, then from my python script I am able to successfully access this using

```
os.environ['GARY']
```

(it returns 'XYZ' as expected)

However I am not able to change the value of the variable `HOMEDRIVE`. When I use `os.environ['HOMEDRIVE']` in my python script, it returns `C:`. So I went to System Properties -> Advanced -> Environment variables, and I created a system variable named `HOMEDRIVE`, and set its value to `X:`. But when I use

```
os.environ['HOMEDRIVE']
```

in my script, it is still returning `C:`

Is it not possible to override the `HOMEDRIVE` and `HOMEPATH` variables? Are these special in some way?

And where exactly are these variables stored, I do not see them in the Environment variables dialog box. Possibly they are stored somewhere else, so even though I am creating a `HOMEDRIVE` system variable in Windows it is being overridden from someplace else.

Comment: Where do you want to use these variables? Can't you just over-ride them in your code: `os.environ['HOMEDRIVE']='D:'`

Comment: Which version of Windows?

Comment: Hi Dhara, this is Windows 7. I haven't tried overriding in my code, I assumed I could probably do that, I was more interested in figuring out why this doesn't work in the first place. The program will be run on many computers on the network, and in some cases I might actually want to respect the HOMEDRIVE setting. It is on the ones that I don't that I was going to ask the users to set this variable in system properties. That is when I realized that does not work for this variable.

Comment: Whenever you set the environment variables you need to restart the command line.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you want to override the variables only in Python, you can do it in code:

```
os.environ['HOMEDRIVE'] = 'D:'
```

If you place this in [sitecustomize.py](http://docs.python.org/2/library/site.html), then it will be run each time you invoke a Python script. From the doc:

> ... an attempt is made to import a module
>   named sitecustomize, which can perform arbitrary site-specific
>   customizations. It is typically created by a system administrator in
>   the site-packages directory.

However, if you want to modify the environment variables in Windows itself, see [this](https://superuser.com/questions/255776/overriding-homedrive-and-homepath-as-a-windows-7-user) superuser stackexchange answer.

Comment: I did not wish to hard code this - I need the computers to use the currently set HOMEDRIVE, I only planned to manually change the HOMEDRIVE in windows environment on certain computers where it is not set correctly. However, from your link to the superuser stackexchange answer I am now wondering if my IT dept settings are forcing HOMEDRIVE to be that value. I haven't determined this for sure yet, but I will go ahead and mark your answer as correct for now. If I later figure out exactly what was the issue, I will post back.

Comment: Great answer! And it makes sense. I was stuck using `os.environ.setdefault(key, val)`, which only sets the variable if the key does not already have a value. This answer provides a meaningful alternative.